# Where do I add the motor leads?

Tags: dc-motor, lcd

I'm making a small type light house and wanted to know where I add the positive and negative leads from the motor onto this circuit board?

I'm just a DIY-er and know hardly anything about circuit boards and electronics, but I'm learning and I've put this together. Only now I wanted to add this little motor to have the light spin.

This is of the first circuit board witch runs the lights and timing:

[image: Pic 1]

Now the second pic is of the LED driver or circuit board in which I'm certain in that I know I add the leads of said motor to I just do not know where:

[image: Pic 2]

Finally, this is the motor with the two wires I'm trying to add to the project and need the most help with. I know the wires from here connect to the board in the second pic, but where?

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. The photos are badly out of focus. The photos should depict both sides of the circuit boards. If you intend that the light spins, wouldn't the power wires turn on in other?

Comment: Ok sorry it it my first post first time doing anything like this I am a special forces career man and don't have any experience in this kind of thing so 4give my photos and un clear question . So I need to take the 2 leads from the motor and hook them up to this circuit board and I don't know where to solder them to I appreciate you taking the time to look at the question I will try to take better pics and be more clear next time . My anxiety on this shit gets the best of me and I loose consintration. But in my case what do u mean by other ? There is a on off switch that I have on the board

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake when I said, _'power wires turn on in other.'_ What I meant to say is that it's unclear how the light will be powered. If the PCB (printed circuit board) with the LED is attached to the motor, what will happen to the wires that power the light when the motor begins to rotate? It seems to me that the two wires powering the light will become **intertwined** with each other, creating a tangle or knot. In this situation, I feel incapable of helping you connect the wires to the motor."